# adding json objects from one file to another under single array using jq

Tags: json, jq

I am new here so sorry if I do any mistakes while asking the question.

I have a json file that keeps updating every minute(File_1.json) with json objects. All i want to do is copy these objects to another file under a single array using the jq command.

Samples of files
File_1.json:

```
        {
          "Id":"1",
          "Name":"Kiran",
          "Age":"12"
        }
        {
          "Id":"2",
          "Name":"Dileep",
          "Age":"22"
        }
```

Expected Output

```
     [ 
       {
          "Id":"1",
          "Name":"Kiran",
          "Age":"12"
        }
        {
          "Id":"2",
          "Name":"Dileep",
          "Age":"22"
        }
       ]
```

I have tried using -s(slurp) but since the code will be running once for every minute its creating multiple arrays.

Comment: Your requirements are unclear as the -s option does exactly what you seem to want.  Are you trying to append the "new" objects to the array in the file produced by the previous iteration? If so, do you want any duplicates to be removed?

Comment: Yes @peak. That is what I want and couldn't put it in words. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted simply to append the objects in File_1.json to an existing array in (say) output.json, you could write:

```
jq  '. + [inputs]' output.json File_1.json
```

This presupposes output.json contains exactly one array (or the JSON value `null`).  So to start, you could initialize output.json by running:

```
echo null > output.json
```

If you want to take the risk and overwrite output.json, you might like to use [`sponge`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/):

```
jq  '. + [inputs]' output.json File_1.json | sponge output.json
```

If you want to remove duplicates and don't mind sorting the objects, you could simply append `| unique` to the above jq filter.  If retaining the order is important, then see
https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#using-bag-to-implement-a-sort-free-version-of-unique